# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have build my website on core php.. and its works fine for me on localhost (Wamp server). but today i just uploaded it online and i am getting this error :-

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

i am using htaccess on my site and here is my htaccess file code

```
 php_flag display_errors off 
php_flag log_errors On 
php_value error_log Logs/PHPError.log
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_reporting 6143
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
php_value register_globals 0 
php_value session.auto_start 0 
ServerSignature Off
DefaultLanguage en
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .css
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
       ExpiresActive On
       ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
       ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
       ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
       ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
       ExpiresByType application/pdf A2592000
       ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
       ExpiresByType text/plain A2592000
       ExpiresByType text/css A10800
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^404$ 404.php 
       RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
       RewriteRule ^Login$ login.php
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^(index|404)\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

can anyone help me to find out how can i solve this trouble?
i have tried to contact with my hosting provider and they answered me that it is developer problem not hosting problem.. but i notice that i need to enable 
"rewrite_module" to use htaccess.. is it that? 
Maybe anyone can help me with this..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You do not need the rewriting module to use `.htaccess` style files. but your `.htaccess`style file does use the rewriting module (`RewriteEngine on...`). So it probably should be enabled...

Comment: Hi mate, yes i noticed it was all fine just i had some trouble with my web hosting providers and they gave me solution.. so now i am using web.config instead of .htaccess and i think its works but i still need to configure web.config file same as .htaccess

Comment: Ah, ok, if your hoster does not use the apache http server but MS-IIS, then obviously a .htaccess style file won't work :-) BTW: That appears to be a _really_ exotic provider. You will run into a lot of other issues too then, since that means that the base for your website is not LAMP (Linux), but MS-Windows. Which is uncommon and insecure for such purpose. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Well yeah, i have noticed no apache on this server... and i can not change my server because i already have paid for this.. and i have some other reasons too... so i think i will have just one way and that is to configure this web.config file..and yeah as you said i will run into a lot of other issues :D